# What does it mean for a set to be contained in another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

If $A$ & $B$ are two sets, what does '$A$ is contained in $B$' mean ? Does it mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $A$ is a proper subset of $B$?

Comment: There is no universal convention, check the one used by the particular author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous, but hopefully it's only used when there is little chance of confusion. If there is a chance, it is better to use notation. Either $A\in B$ for $A$ being an element of $B$, or $A\subseteq B$ for $A$ being a subset of $B$.

If it's the latter, generally it is not necessarily a proper subset. Authors however can do whatever they want, as long as they define it. You have to watch out for nonstandard language and notation.

Comment: @Thomas Started writing it on my phone, had to do something else, must've accidentally posted it without finishing. Thanks.

Comment: I would go as far as saying that writing "$A$ is contained in $B$" and meaning $A\in B$ amounts to gaslighting...

Comment: @Julius Sets can contain elements. And in set theory everything is a set. So in situations like that it can legitimately be ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not commenting on the mathematical content, but on pedagogy and custom. Some people define "cat" to mean "dog" and "up" to mean "down". Saying "$A$ is contained in $B$" and meaning "$A$ is an element of $B$" seems so cruel to me, especially when this is very standard terminology. But hey, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: I DO NOT disagree with you answer, so don't take offense.

Comment: @Julius Sure, none taken.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that "$A$ is contained in $B$" means is that the implication

$$x \in A \implies x \in B $$

is satisfied. It could be a proper or non-proper subset. Often, when the subset is proper, most authors explicitely state this.